# fadeIn effect to background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How Could I add a fadeIn(); effect to the changing backg5round image on click? The current code below works but with no fade effect.

html

```
<div class="background"></div>
```

css

```
.background {position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top;background-image:url(images/skins/BiblesandCommentaries.jpg);}
```

js

```
$('.selector').click(function() {
    $('.background').css({'background-image':'url(images/skins/'+$(this).attr('href').replace('#', '') +'.jpg'+')'});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a smoother experience, it would help to preload the image followed by changing the background-image. [Here's the below script on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktHhG/), with a slight change to accommodate the image sources:

```
$('.selector').click(function() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'images/skins/'+$(this).attr('href').replace('#', '') +'.jpg';
    img.onload = function () {
        $('.background').fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).css({'background-image':'url('+img.src+')'}).fadeIn();
        });
    };
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: I've updated the example for you with a more fitting solution.

Answer (score 1):

the current CSS for the background can be set to

```
.background {
    visibility:hidden;
}


$('.selector').click(function() {
    $('.background').css(....).fadeIn();
});
```